# the definition of Applicative instance implementation for Maybe (Haskell/LYAH)

Tags: haskell

Many times I tried to understand Functor and Monad in Haskell, but I failed. This time when I reached at LYAH's [Applicative Functor](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors),  and thought I understood `Applicative typeclasses`, but I had some doubt about Applicative instance implementation for Maybe：

```
instance Applicative Maybe where  
pure = Just  
Nothing <*> _ = Nothing  
(Just f) <*> something = fmap f something
```

For the last line of above snippet, my understanding as follows:

(1) `Just f` is appropriated to `f (a->b)` in `(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` of class definition of Applicative, and `f` is appropriated to `(a->b)`

(2) `something` is appropriated to `f a`.

my question is from (2),  why there is not written like `Just something` or the like?

In the [Functor instance implementation for Maybe](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass), there is `fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)` and `Just x` is appropriated to `f a` of `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

for verifying my understanding, I changed `something` into `Just something`:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where  
pure = Just  
Nothing <*> _ = Nothing  
(Just f) <*> (Just something) = fmap f (Just something)
```

under gchi, I tried

```
Just (+3) <*> Just 9
```

and got the same result `Just 12`, but when I tried

```
Just (++"hahah") <*> Nothing`
```

I got the error

```
*** Exception: Functor.hs:(88,3)-(89,60): Non-exhaustive patterns in function <*>
```

I don't know why or what things I miss?

Comment: `(Just f) <*> something` and `(Just f) <*> (Just something)` are not equivalent; `something` is just a variable and matches anything, including the constructor `Nothing`, while `Just something` will not match nothing. Your idea will work correctly if you have *also* have `Just _ <*> Nothing = Nothing`. However, this is 3 lines, and programmers are lazy, so why write something in 3 lines that can be written in 2?

Comment: @user2407038, "matches anything" you said means `something` included `Just somthing`?

Comment: @user2407038 "so why write something in 3 lines that can be written in 2?" means the `_` in line 2 can be replaced by `something` (of course I have tested it using `something` in line 2)? the reason for using `_` is laziness?

Comment: This is the same problem you would get if you define a function as only `f :: Maybe Int; f (Just x) = x + 1` and try to call `f Nothing`.

Comment: Yes, the pattern `something` will match `Just x`. `_` is equally as lazy as just a variable. So `Nothing <*> x = Nothing` would behave exactly the same way. The purpose of `_` is to communicate to readers of your program that that parameter is not used.

Comment: Well-written question, thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: When you have the pattern `(Just f) <*> (Just x)`, you can do without `fmap`: `(Just f) <*> (Just x) = Just (f x)`. This is the point of the pattern.

Comment: @Franky Thank you! Can you explain more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is an extension of my comment and does not really answer the question)

This alternate definition is easier to grasp:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where  
    pure = Just  
    (Just f) <*> (Just x) = Just (f x)
    _        <*> _        = Nothing
```

I think you fell into the trap of interpreting too much out of the name `something`. I always try to name the variables `f` and `x` in the context of applicatives (in the context of `<*>`, to be precise), that's just what they are, a function and a value the function is applied to.

Answer (score 3):

```
instance Applicative Maybe where  
pure = Just  
Nothing <*> _ = Nothing  
(Just f) <*> (Just something) = fmap f (Just something)
```

We can see whats wrong just by looking at the patterns! The first will match anything whose first parameter is `Nothing`, but the second will only match if it is both `Just ...`. Nothing matches `Just f` and `Nothing`. Just because the first parameter is not `Nothing` doesn't mean the second has to be. If you really wanted to be explicit, you could write `_ <*> Nothing = Nothing` above the last line.